# Closing realm instance

Tags: java, android, realm

I've encounter that realm database has grown to 1GB overtime. When I do compact (when the application starts), it went down to about 300Kb.

I did my research and people mentioned that I must close my realm database. But in all my threads that accessing the realm, I do the following:

```
try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance())
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //put in the log here
}
```

Most of my data are cached, so only load it once (unless I need to save to DB and sync the cached data, then I open realm - which happen quiet often).

So, my question is, does `try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance())` is good enough? Or should I do `try {...} catch{...} finally { realm.close(); }` like the following?

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
try
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //put in the log here
}
finally
{
    realm.close();
}
```

Currently, I am calling compactRealm() every time I start the app. It is very slow though, but managed to reduce the size to around 300Kb.

Thanks!

PS.
I can't store *Realm* instance as a class instance because most of the operation is done inside the thread (saving new data, sync data with the cache, etc).

Comment: Both code are the same...  First one is just a shortcut for this AutoCloseable

Comment: Hmmm... I can't figure out then what causing the size to blew up from few kilobytes to a gigabyte. I don't like to call `compactRealm()` when loading my app as it slows down the loading of my app :(

Comment: @Sam Do you have open Realm instances in multiple threads? If you have a non-Looper thread with an open Realm instance, that instance will stay at an old version, and you will see an increase of size. See also https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#large-realm-file-size

Comment: hi geisshirt, yes, it is from non-looper thread. But the thread is short lived. Normally it is used to load db to cached data and to save a new data. That is why I used `try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance())` which I assumed will close the database once I finish?

Comment: Yes, try-with-resources should guarantee that the Realm is closed when you exit the closure. Most likely you missed doing that somewhere?

Comment: Yes, try-with-resources should guarantee that the Realm is closed when you exit the closure. Most likely you missed doing that somewhere?

Comment: Hi Christian, I've checked and re-check my code. All Realm are open using `try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance())`. The only thing I can think off is deleting objects. When I delete object, does realm keep the space?

Comment: Yes. Realm will retain all space allocated, even if you delete the objects. Calling `Realm.compactRealm(config)` is currently the only way to reduce the filesize. It is something we want to improve upon, but we do not have any timeline right now.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for confirming the behavior. Please post your answer and I'll accept it.